# How to get EnvelopeID & Recipient view URL of Powerform in docusign using C#?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are planning to integrate the docusign powerfroms in the upcoming project. After intiation of powerfrom will genreate the Envelope ID (Need to track in DB). We are unable to find the EnvelopeID. So how we can get EnvelopeID ? And Recipient view URl after creating sender envelope?

Answer (score 0):

**Finding the Envelope ID**
When a Powerform signing session is finished, DocuSign redirects to a URL (you can configure the base URL) which contains a number of URL parameters of which the Envelope Id (env) is one: env={envelope-id}. You will likely be interested in the evt parameter also. This indicates if the recipient completed their requested actions, or declined, session timed out etc.

**Recipient View**
You cannot get a Recipient View for an envelope created via a Powerform. You can only get a Recipient View for an envelope created via an API call where the Recipient(s) in question were specified as being captive/embedded (clientUserId element present in the Recipient structure).

If you must use Poweforms, you could create a Powerform in which the first Recipient is embedded (Direct Signing Mode). Typically using this method the Powerform has a 'front end' which redirects the browser to the Powerform URL, passing in additional relevant information such as the recipient name. The user would then be presented with the DocuSign signing session (similar to Recipient View). One of the limitations here is all remaining Recipients (if any) would need to be remote, i.e. not embedded/captive.

Comment: I have configured Default Landing Pages for PowerForms as u suggesst in following format

http://Site/DocuSign?env={envelope-id}&action=SigningComplete

I will be giving following output

http://Site/DocuSign?env={envelope-id}&action=SigningComplete&pf=GUID&r=GUID

In this "env" nothing coming , "pf" is PowerForm ID May I know what id is coming in "r" query string? and Is it possible to get the document using API by using the ID coming from Query string "r"?

Comment: The information "You cannot get a Recipient View for an envelope created via a Powerform" is incorrect, you can certainly do this if you needed to.

Comment: Don't you need the clientUserId to get a Recipient View? How is this set when an envelope is created via a Powerform?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured Default Landing Pages for PowerForms as u suggesst in following format

http://Site/DocuSign?env={envelope-id}&action=SigningComplete

I will be giving follwing output

http://Site/DocuSign?env={envelope-id}&action=SigningComplete&pf=2b125d0d-b682-4ee5-94db-bbe3c2351a12&r=7dadf63d-808a-4c63-b918-f26afad78886

In this 
"env" nothing coming
"action" type of action defined Landing Pages for PowerForm
"pf" is PowerForm ID
May I know what id is coming in "r" query string?
and Is it possible to get the document using API by using the ID coming from Query string "r"?

Comment: env and status should be coming back automatically, take it out of your landing pages url and see if it starts coming back correctly.

Comment: The 'r' value is a recipient GUID, so no you cannot use this alone to retrieve a document via the API.